# How to handle program closing event on a normal python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

if someone press the X button on the tab in the program or simply do ctr-c if its command line program then how do i handle the closing event for example if i want to write you have left the program by your self in a file after he close the program .
is there any library or function for that?

Comment: For ctrl+C you can `try`-`except KeyboardInterrupt`. What do you mean by "press the X button on the tab in the program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a function to be executed at exit. See the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module.

For example, this will call `print('goodbye.')` when exiting:

```
atexit.register(print, 'goodbye.')
```

You can also register any other function which will do the cleanup you need.

Comment: How to install the library ?

Comment: @OussemaNehdi It's in the standard library. You don't need to install it; it comes with Python.

Comment: it does the functions on multiprocess?

Comment: also does this  catch other OS level interrupts ?